# ValueError: View function did not return a response in flask

Tags: python, flask

So there are several of this questions already asked and the error for this means that the function has to return a value, or simply means it should return something.

I already have it in my routes.py file but its still not working.

Here is the code for route.py

```
from flask import *
from functools import wraps
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "my precious"

@app.route('/')
def home():
     return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')

@app.route('/logout')   
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in',None)
    return redirect (url_for('home'))

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html')


@app.route('/log', methods=['GET','POST'])
def log():
    error = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or  request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = "Invalid credentials"
        else: 
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect (url_for('hello'))
        return render_template('log.html', error=error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Code for log.html

```
{% extends "templates.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Login</h1>
    {% If error %}
        <p class=error> <strong> Error: </strong> {{ error }}
    {% endif %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <dl>
            <dt>Username:
            <dt><input type="text" name="username" value="{{
            request.form.username }}">
            <dt>Password:
            <dd><input type="password" name="passowrd"> 
        </dl>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Login">      
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

code for templates.html

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Flask tutorial (Part 1)</title>
</head>
    <header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">  
        <a class="brand" href="/">Real python (for the web!)</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/welcome">Welcome</a></li>
            <li><a href="/log">login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

code for home.html

```
{% extends "templates.html"%}
{% block content %}
    <div class="jumbo">
        <h2>Welcome to Flask</h2>
        <br/>
        <p>click <a href="/welcome">here</a> to go to welcome page</p>
    </div>  
{% endblock %}
```

code for hello.html

```
{% extends "templates.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Welcome! You are logged in.</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

code for welcome.html

```
{% extends "templates.html"%}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Sample</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Can someone help me where I am going wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `log()` method does not return a response if you're accessing it via `GET`.
Your question is a bit uninformative where the error is happening, but this is what I can deduce.

Edit: Looking into the video, it is indeed the `log` method that is causing you trouble.
You've accidentally indented too deep.

```
@app.route('/log', methods=['GET','POST'])
def log():
    error = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or  request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = "Invalid credentials"
        else: 
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect (url_for('hello'))
    return render_template('log.html', error=error)
```

Comment: Hi limelights, Thanks for replying I removed GET from methods=['GET','POST']. Again I got this error: The method is not allowed for the requested URL. Can you suggest me what should I do? This code is from a tutorial that I am learning for flask

Comment: Without any more information from you it'll be very hard to further help you. Useful information is usually where are you getting the error, can you post it? What tutorial are you using?

Comment: Hi! thanks I am going through video tutorials from youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCpNvteLCDI (Currently on video no 3, have finished 1st and the second one). I will also add some of the other pages that I  have created following the tutorial.

Comment: Hi I got your point, it was due to indentation that return was not detected. But after correcting it I still get this error called: The method is not allowed for the requested URL on log.html

Comment: Did you re-add `GET`?

Comment: Thanks a ton! its working now. Had deleted GET, added it back. thanks a ton :)

Comment: Cool, happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered a few times but it took me a while to understand what I was looking for specific to my (subtly different) problem, so I just want to throw in that the generic answer here is this:

Somewhere in your code, you're defining a route but not returning anything. This code returns a template:

```
@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template("welcome.html")
```

This code only returns a template under some circumstances:

```
@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return render_template("welcome.html")
```

So if you're really not sure why you are seeing `ValueError: View function did not return a response` walk through your code and make sure that all your route definitions (`def foo():`) actually `return` something, and that something isn't nested inside of an if clause

It is pretty annoying that the error doesn't give a lot of clues about where it is getting stuck, but I'm sure a more experienced Pythoner could explain why that is.